# Prove $S=aT$ for some $a\in F$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. Let $S,T\colon V\to F$ be linear transformations. Assume that $N(T)\subseteq N(S)$. Show that there exists $a\in F$ such that $S=aT$.

$N(T)$ and $N(S)$ are the null spaces.

I've messed around with this problem for a couple hours but I didn't really get anywhere. I thought about showing that $S(v)/T(v)$ is a constant for all $v$ or showing that $S$ and $T$ are linearly dependent in the vector space $L(V,F)$ of all linear transformations from $V$ to $F$.

Can anyone outline a solution?

Comment: This can't be right. Let $S=\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}$, let $T$ be the identity. The nullspace of $T$ is just the zero vector, which is contained in the nullspace of $S$, but $S$ is not a scalar multiple of $T$.

Comment: What would be $V$ and $F$ in your example?

Comment: $F$ could be any field (the reals, if you like), and $V$ would be the vector space of ordered pairs of elements of $F$ (that is, $V=F^2$).

Comment: That is indeed a counter example.

Comment: Wait a second, the transformation has to be from $V$ to $F$. In your example it is from $V$ to $V$ isn't it?

Comment: @WinstonTsai V is allowed to equal F, so we have a map F $\rightarrow$ F.

Comment: Sorry, Winston, I missed that condition.

Answer (score 1):

Either $\ker S=V$, in which case just let $a=0$, or $S\neq 0$, in which case $\ker T\subseteq\ker S$ gives $\operatorname{codim}\ker T\geqslant 1$ and hence $\ker T=\ker S$ (since $\operatorname{codim}\ker T\leqslant 1$ from $T\colon V\to F$).  Pick $v\in V$ with $v\notin\ker T$ so $Tv\neq 0$ and let $a=\dfrac{Sv}{Tv}$.  Since $\operatorname{codim}\ker T=1$ we have every $v'\in V$ satisfies $v'-\lambda v\in\ker T$ for some $\lambda\in F$ and hence $$Sv'=\bar{S}(v'+\ker T)=\lambda\bar{S}(v+\ker T)=\lambda aTv=aTv'$$
where $\bar{S}\colon V/\ker T\to F$ is the induced map from $\ker T\subseteq\ker S$.